# How to add extra data in a json request

Tags: groovy, soapui

In my SOAP UI ihave two steps, a groovy script step and a rest request step for a POST crud method.

In the groovy script I am creating a random test case property named 'adults'. This value is a random value between 2-5.

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('adults', String.valueOf((int)Math.random()*5)+2);
```

Below is my rest request for the POST:

```
{
  "xxx": "xxx",
  "ratePlanCode": "xxx"
  "roomOccupancies": [
    {
      "passengersInformation": [
        {
          "firstName": "Test",
          "lastName": "Tester",
          "isLeadPassenger": true,
          "age": 30
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
  "xxx": "xxx"
}
```

Now this request is fixed for 1 adult passenger, but the issue is that if I have multiple passengers, I actually need multiple passengers under "passengersInformation". So virtually for every extra adult I need to add:

```
{
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Tester",
      "isLeadPassenger": false,
      "age": 30
    },
```

So what i am thinking is for the name of the passenger as we are not allowed duplicate names, we just add a number to the end of the first and last name. The other two fields we can keep the same.

So my question is how do we add additional passenger details within the request based on the number of adults randomly selected from the groovy script?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to replicate the passenger: Note I had to fix a couple of commas (extra and missing) in the JSON string.

```
import groovy.json.*
def jsonData = '''{
  "hotelArrivalDate": "2017-06-01T18:15:00",
  "ratePlanCode": "xxx=",
  "roomOccupancies": [
    {
      "passengersInformation": [
        {
          "firstName": "Test",
          "lastName": "Tester",
          "isLeadPassenger": true,
          "age": 30
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "holidaysBookingReference": "TestRef"
}'''
def n=1
def data = (new JsonSlurper()).parseText(jsonData)
def newPerson = data.roomOccupancies[0].
                     passengersInformation[0].
                     collectEntries {k,v -> 
                         ['firstName','lastName'].contains(k) ? [k,v+n] : [k,v]
                     }
data.roomOccupancies[0].passengersInformation << newPerson
jsonData = (new JsonBuilder(data)).toPrettyString()
```

result

```
{
    "hotelArrivalDate": "2017-06-01T18:15:00",
    "ratePlanCode": "xxx=",
    "roomOccupancies": [
        {
            "passengersInformation": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Test",
                    "lastName": "Tester",
                    "isLeadPassenger": true,
                    "age": 30
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "Test1",
                    "lastName": "Tester1",
                    "isLeadPassenger": true,
                    "age": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "holidaysBookingReference": "TestRef"
}
```